# How to Prevent PHP Allowed Memory Size Fatal Error from query result?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, memory-leaks

I have a (cake) php function designed to update entries in a MySQL table; first of all it runs a query to get all the new items since a $lastImportDate, and then loops through performing various actions on the item, saving the item, saving related table information.

Unfortunately this seems to be collapsing under the excessive weight of one particular request.  Here there are 5917 (and probably counting!) entries to update.  The function loops through for a while, but eventually dies with an "Allowed memory size of [lots of bytes] exhausted" error.

Without forcing anyone to wade through extensive code - what strategies can I reasonably adopt to try to stop this memory leak from rendering this table un-updateable?

Comment: You can try to perform all the tasks on the database side (using more complex SQL queries).

Comment: Or you can try this approach that shouldn't consume so much memory (because it iterates over the result and does not store all the entries to the memory at once): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285600/how-to-iterate-by-row-through-a-mysql-query-in-php/2285623#2285623

Comment: Process each row as you read them from your database resource. Don't store them in a variable as then you will run out of memory.

Comment: These comments sound promising - I don't suppose anyone reading has an example of doing such a thing in a CakePHP framework?  (Probably asking a lot...)

Comment: Additionally, if you need an array for storing data and can't go without it - I'd use SPL class `SplFixedArray` to store the database records. It's about 37% more memory efficient than the conventional means of creating an array in PHP. Refer to PHP docs for usage.

Comment: could you show the exact actions you are performing on the items?

Comment: @Aurimas, I think I do need to look closely into the actions being performed, because something is definitely up.  I'm going to try and narrow down the possible problematic areas before dumping screens of code on people though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can always try setting:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

[[docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)]

Or a [more appropriate value](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/777/solve-php-fatal-error-allowed-memory-size-of-8388608-bytes-exhausted-tried/)

Alternatively, farm more out to SQL (using [CASE](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/933-Using-CASE-Statements-In-A-SQL-UPDATE-Query.htm) updates, or nested select updates), or set up a [cron job](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/running-php-cron-jobs-regular-scheduled-tasks-in-php-172/) to launch the script in smaller intervals until the update is complete...

Comment: I think the memory limit has been pushed up to 512M at the moment, which seems a bit ridiculous already.  Trying to avoid this route if at all possible!

Comment: Ouch- seems incredibly high. I'd likely look at optimising your SQL, then trating it like a batch job and using a cron job to schedule repeat staggered executions of the script (which escapes a single incidence timing out).

Answer (score 1):

Sound like you are saving all the records in a variable. Try getting only the ID's, then looping through the ID's. You get every record by doing $this->Model->findById($id) and do your actions on that particular record. Then you save that record and unset the data, this way you'll never have much data stored in variables. It doesn't surprise me you run out of memory if you put everything in one variable.

Increasing memory limit is just a bad temporary solution, imagine having to update 100000 or more records. Eventually you'll run out.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know exactly the nature of the task you need to accomplish. If you need to update entries with a regular interval: Make a Cake Shell, put it in cron schedule (run every hour if you have to).

If you need to perform an update every time you do an import to the DB: you can try `loop{ get and process 100 records, repeat until done}` Try to maximize the number of records you can process before hitting the memory limit.