# how to iterate through mysql_query() result

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to iterate by row through a mysql query in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285600/how-to-iterate-by-row-through-a-mysql-query-in-php)

After:

```
 $result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: Cant query database");
```

All Im trying to do is iterate through the result one by one and display the values separated by ";" in order from top to bottom, left to right;

I'm actually embarrassed I have to ask this "easy" question but Im not getting results lol. Might be the structure of the returned resource Im not getting, who knows.

I dont want to have to plugin in row or fields names, I just want to iterate through and display it, regardless of the result.

Comment: Note that you should no longer use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and are [being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead, you should be using either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? Then [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.

Comment: Have you tried any of the provided examples http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php ?

Comment: Sorry for voting down on your questing, but I get the feeling you did not do any research yourself. A simple search "mysql iterate results" would have given you the answer in 3 secs.

Comment: Well I did do a search, just didnt use the right keywords

Comment: @Jonah Bishop thats really good to know

Comment: If you're stumped on how to use `mysql_query`, you need a better reference, and preferably one that's not fifteen years out of date. [Learning PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) is probably the best thing you could do at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   // Your code goes here...
   // OR
   echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

check: http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-query.php

If you want to display specific columns of the result:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['address'];
    echo $row['age'];
}
```

or just the whole set of result:

```
$result_set = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) or die(mysql_error());
echo '<pre>';var_dump($result_set);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of the answer I was given, that fits my specifications of being Comma delimited. Just in case their are others looking for the same thing.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Error: Cant query database");

while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
    foreach ($line as $col_value) 
    {
        echo $col_value.";";
    }   
}
```