# Iterate through Mysql Rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to iterate by row through a mysql query in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285600/how-to-iterate-by-row-through-a-mysql-query-in-php)

I need to iterate thorough the mysql rows. For an example, if question id is 1 all the answers have to display under the question 1. I am a beginner to php , can any one please help me??

[image]

---

```
<?php
            $result = select("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id=1");
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


        ?>
<table width="581" height="299" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Union Assurance Questionnaire</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1.<?php echo $row['questions']; ?>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <?php
            $result = select("SELECT * FROM questions WHERE question_id=2");
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


        ?>
<table width="581" height="299" border="1">

  <tr>
    <td>2.<?php echo $row['questions']; ?>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What answers? None of your code/tables show any answers, except a fields in your screencap with 'answer' in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use like this

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<table width="581" height="299" border="1">
<tr>
<td>Union Assurance Questionnaire</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1.<?php echo $row['questions']; ?>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php
}
?>
```

You have to use `while() loop` for iterating all possible answers.

Comment: I Have add your code, but first row question is not showing on the page, d u have any idea??/

Comment: `first row question is not showing on the page`, can you explain this??

Comment: sorry, that was my false, it is working now....