# php mysqli help, first line in DB not being returned?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my code

```
     <?php require_once 'connect.php';

                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `db-pages`";
                    $result = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
                        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo($row['pagetitle'].' - To edit this page <a href="editpage.php?id='.$row['id'].'">click here</a><br>');
 }  
                    }
      ?>
```

I've added a couple more rows to the Database and it's returning them all, apart from id=1 in the DB. Any idea why?

Comment: what is result `echo mysqli_num_rows($result)`

Comment: try to check count of returned rows before you do the while, use `echo $result->num_rows;`

Comment: @GBD you forgot the `i` in `mysql`. @wiiliamsongibson: how many data are there in database?

Comment: You can find and answer to a similar question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285600/how-to-iterate-by-row-through-a-mysql-query-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it like this:

```
 while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo($row['pagetitle'].' - To edit this page <a href="editpage.php?id='.$row['id'].'">click here</a><br>');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've added your example above and more than 2 rows in the DB. It is working, but the first row id=1 is never displayed. Any idea why?

Comment: what if you printed the mysqli_fetch_assoc(), what is shown?
print_r(mysqli_fetch_assoc());

Answer (score 1):

Double check the title and ensure it's got nothing that will affect php out-putting it.

Also escape all of your DB output using htmlentities, it makes for good practise in the event someone gets creative.